# Jaspersoft Server V5.5 Catalogue Import Creates Directories in Repository But No Reports, Import Controls, Or Queries Are Imported

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a zip file created using the Export function in Jaspersoft Server V5.5. This zip file contains a catalogue of all reports, input controls, and queries from a development server.

When I try to import the catalogue to V5.5 on my production server by logging in as superuser and going to "Manage > Server Settings > Import", selecting the zip file, and clicking Submit, I receive an "Import Succeeded" message.

When I check the repository however, most of the directories have been created (but not the input control or queries folders) but none of the actual reports, input controls or queries have been imported.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to modify any of the files within the zip file?